# Handling default values with global variables in python

Tags: python

i am trying the following code:

```
import simplegui
import random
import math
def new_game():
   global secret_number
   global low
   global high
   global n
   print "New game. Range is from" ,low ,"-",high
   secret_number=random.randrange(low,high)
   n=math.ceil(math.log((high-low+1),2))
   print "no of guesses",n
   print " "

def new_game1():
   global secret_number
   print "New game. Range is from 0-100"
   print " "
   secret_number=random.randrange(0,100)    


# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    global low,high
    low=0
    high=100
    new_game()

def range1000():
    global low
    global high
    low=0
    high=1000
    new_game()


def input_guess(guess):
    global secret_number
    global n
    g=int(guess)
    print "Guess was",g
    --n
    print "no of guesses left",n
    if(g>secret_number):
        print "Lower"
    elif(g<secret_number):
        print "Higher"
    else:
        print "Equal"


frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 200, 200)
button1 = frame.add_button('Range is(0,100)', range100,200)
button2 = frame.add_button('Range is(0,1000)', range1000,200)
inp = frame.add_input('Enter a guess', input_guess,200)
frame.start()
new_game1()
```

the problem with my above code is that I want to use a single newgame() fn which takes the default value of low as 0 and high as 100 . Right now I have bifurcated that function into newgame1() which is doing computations on the default values

How to rectify this problem? Please help

Comment: Is there any reason why all your variables need to be global? You could possibly make them local and use default arguments to save yourself some trouble.

Comment: how can i save in low=0 and high=100 for newgame()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the limits as global variables you could send them as function arguments. You can set the default values to something and override them as needed. `new_game()` might become something like:

```
def new_game( low = 0, high = 100 ):
    global secret_number, n    # Maybe these can be function arguments as well?
    print "New game. Range is from" ,low ,"-",high
    secret_number=random.randrange(low,high)
    n=math.ceil(math.log((high-low+1),2))
    print "no of guesses",n
    print " "
```

Your `range` functions would become:

```
def range100():
    new_game() # high & low take default values of 0,100

def range1000():
    new_game(high = 1000) # high is now 1000

# My own function
def rangeMinus1000():
    new_game(low = -100, high = 1000) # low is -100 & high is 1000
```

Comment: actually the question wants new_game to be a function with no arguments

Comment: That is unfortunately impossible. You might want to call a function like `resetRange()` after `new_game()` to reset to default values.